# boost::serialize, test if object is serializeable

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I am attempting to write a function that uses boost::serialize if an object can be serialized, with a fallback if the object cannot be written with boost::serialize.  Is there some template-based way to test whether an a given class can be serialized?

```
 // ideally, something of this form
 is_boost_serializeable<T>::value
```

I know that I can use SFINAE to check for the existence of individual methods, but with the many different options on how to provide a serialization, I'm worried that I would miss some edge cases.  As it is, I haven't been able to find anything in the boost documentation describing such a function existing already.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586624/trait-which-checks-whether-class-has-typedef-private-or-other-or-not That OP wanted to dump/serialize an object/class (i.e. similar to what you're looking for) When I was researching it, my best guess that friending the class would be required. boorg's answer may work but I didn't test it. In other words, each serializable class has to _cooperate_ by providing a common method name. Otherwise, how do you know if there are three ways to serialize: Tom, Dick, or Harry.

Comment: How would that work, practically? You can't mix boost archives with non-archive data anyways

Comment: @CraigEstey This is true, that each class must provide some method in order to serialize this.  Reading through the boost::serialization documentation, I can see how to create that common method name.  What I am uncertain on is not how to create my own class capable of being serialized with boost, but rather how to test whether some template parameter `T` is capable of being serialized.

Comment: @sehe This is for the packing/unpacking of a message passed through TCP after it has been split into a `std::vector<char>`.  One way to pack/unpack the data would be by creating a `boost::archive::text_iarchive`/`test_oarchive`.  I have successfully done this before, but now want to test whether or not it is possible for a user-defined class.  That way, if it is not possible, I can potentially fall back to other methods.